# How can you convert a variable into denary in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, hex, ascii

I have had problems with converting strings (like inputs) into denary, as a string is a necessary for using hexadecimal (as it can't be stored as an integer because of the characters a-f being included). Here are two attempts that don't work:

```py
>>> hex_number = 'ff' #(255 in denary)
>>> ascii(0xhex_number)
SyntaxError: invalid hexadecimal literal
>>> ascii('0x'+hex_number)
"'0xff'"
```

I have also seen that you can use `format()` somehow, but that didn't work either.

```py
>>> format(hex_number, '16') #This was what the demo said to do.
'ff              '
```

How can I get it so that `hex_number` (hexadecimal) is converted to denary (aka decimal), or any other n-base number systems?

Comment: `int('ff', 16)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn the string into an `int` then back into a string

```py
>>> n = int('ff', 16); n
255
>>> f'{n:d}'
'255'
```

Comment: Oh. I didn't realise that you could adapt int() for n-base numerics. Does that make ascii() completely useless then?

Comment: I'm sure that `ascii` is useful for text (e.g. `ümlaut` or `\xfcmlaut`), but I have never personally had a need for it. _For numbers, do not use ascii_. Everything can be done through the "master" integer representation of a number, and convert to/from string representations on input/output.